# Selecting Radio button on Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to selecting one of radio button on such a test web application. after try and error i couldn't find out how to do it.

Here is the HTML of the web apps.

```
    <ol class="plain block-listing solid choice-area">
    <li class="qti-choice qti-simpleChoice"data-serial="choice_simplechoice_56c2a110874b8101352859" data-identifier="choice_1">
    <div class="pseudo-label-box">
    <label class="real-label">
    <input type="radio" value="choice_1" name="response-interaction_choiceinteraction_56c2a1108692f930922645">
    <span class="icon-radio"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="label-box">
    <div class="label-content clear" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="qti-block">a. Terminal</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="qti-choice qti-simpleChoice" data-serial="choice_simplechoice_56c2a110878f8127430456" data-identifier="choice_2">
    <div class="pseudo-label-box">
    <label class="real-label">
    <input type="radio" value="choice_2" name="response-interaction_choiceinteraction_56c2a1108692f930922645">
    <span class="icon-radio"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="label-box">
    <div class="label-content clear" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="qti-block">b. Pelabuhan</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
```

On my selenium Webdriver, here is my code :

```
    WebElement choiceOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div/label/span"));
    choiceOption.click();
```

Anyone can help? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `"//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div/label/span"` is not very maintainable. Almost any structural change will break your test.

Comment: Noted, Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input tag of radio button to select it
Try this :
WebElement choiceOption = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
    choiceOption.click();

Comment: Hi Bhumi, i'll try this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an absolute path, you can go with relative path and there are multiple ways to locate this webelement.
One of the simplest xpath would be :
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='choice_1']")).click();

Comment: Hi Randhika, i'll try this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes same answer

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='real-label']//*[@value='choice_2']")).click();
//The above code selects the option "Pelabuhan"
```

Comment: Hi Deo, i've tried your suggestion, but its still return with exception NoSuchElement. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it multiple ways.

1. Get all option elements, loop through and click the one with the value you need.

   List options = driver.findElements(By.css("ol.plain.block-listing.solid.choice-area input")
   for(option in options){
            if(option.value=="choice_2"){
               if(!option.isChecked()) option.click();
               break;
         }
   }

   }
2. A simple way is, you can build a dynamic x-path or css with the value you wanted to click.. For example  if choice_2 is what we wanted to click

   WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.css(input[value='choice_2']));
   if(!option.isChecked())  option.click();

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Prakash, i'll try this. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In a method first, find Webelement of ol tag, in ol find List of input tag and apply for loop for input tag list and match with value of the input tag to click

Try below code:

`

```
myMethod(String inputTagValue){
WebElement olTag = driver.findElement(By.tagName("ol"));
List<WebElement> inputTagList = olTag.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
for (WebElement item: inputTagList ) {
                if(item.getAttribute("value").equals(inputTagValue)){
                    item.click();
                    break;
                }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Hi Sandeep, i'll try this. Thank you for your help.